# Postfix configuration check recipient

Tags: postfix

I have set up my Posfix email SMTP server on Ubuntu 16 and it's working. I used to use the SMTP server of my hosting company but I rather use my own.

I'm sending email with Java Mail but the difference is that when I send trough hosting company and the recipient address is wrong I get:

com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPAddressFailedException: 450 4.1.2 : Recipient address rejected: Domain not found

But when I send with Postfix no Exception is thrown. I check the Postfix log and the message is:

Action: failed Status: 5.4.4 Diagnostic-Code: X-Postfix; Host or domain name not found. Name service error for name=somebod@ggmail.com type=AAAA: Host not found

But this is never propagated as java exception.

Anybody has a clue how to set up Postfix to behave the same way?

Thanks,
Hugo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put `reject_unknown_recipient_domain` in `smtpd_recipient_restrictions` **before** `permit_mynetworks`, `permit_sasl_authenticated`, and/or `permit_tls_clientcerts`.

If `reject_unknown_sender_domain` is missing from the config, or if `permit_*` appears before `reject_unknown_sender_domain` then postfix will allow all client senders matching the permit rule to send email without the recipient domain being checked.  Postfix will accept the incoming mail, queue it, and only notice the domain doesn't exist when it attempts to deliver it....and then bounce the message.

If `reject_unknown_sender_domain` appears first, then it is checked for all clients, whether they match a `permit_*` rule or not, and the email is rejected with a 5xx code.

In postfix, the order of rules is always significant.

Example:

If you have the following in `main.cf`:

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/junk,
  check_client_access hash:/etc/postfix/junk,
  check_helo_access hash:/etc/postfix/junk,
  reject_unauth_pipelining,
  permit_tls_clientcerts,
  permit_sasl_authenticated,
  permit_mynetworks
```

add `reject_unknown_recipient_domain` somewhere before the `permit` lines, e.g.:

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/junk,
  check_client_access hash:/etc/postfix/junk,
  check_helo_access hash:/etc/postfix/junk,
  reject_unauth_pipelining,
  reject_unknown_recipient_domain,
  permit_tls_clientcerts,
  permit_sasl_authenticated,
  permit_mynetworks
```

If you don't already have a `smtpd_recipient_restrictions` rule, add one like:

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = reject_unauth_pipelining,
  reject_unknown_recipient_domain,
  permit_mynetworks
```

You should, however, do some more research on configuring postfix.

Comment: Hi,
Do I add this line in main.cf?

smtpd_recipient_restrictions = reject_unknown_recipient_domain
before line
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks ....

Comment: yes.  there will probably be an existing `smtpd_recipient_restrictions=...` rule in `main.cf` - edit that if there is.  otherwise add one.

Comment: I actually only want to use postfix for sending email from localhost

Comment: Hi. A followup question.
Is it possible to configure postfix to have a Exception thrown also when mail is bounced? Tanks.